# Intent to Receive Xero and Zoho Flow

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I am trying to setup a Webhook in Zoho Flow that receives information from Xero Accounting.
On the Xero Developer side, clicking on "Intent to Receive" sends data to the Webhook URL I have setup in Zoho Flow. "Intent to receive" is failing because the HTTP response is not returning `"Status Ok 200"` or `"Status Unathourised 401"` correctly.

Does anyone have any experience setting this up? There is very limited documentation for Zoho Flow webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be good to try  the Xero Accounting call via curl to see what HTTP responses Xero is returning.  That may help with adjusting the Zoho Flow configuration.